# Problema con conexión ssh inversa "tunnel"

Tags: linux, servidor, ssh

Actualmente he configurado una conexión por tunnel mediante ssh, obviamente usando una clave publica, en algunos momentos se conecta sin problemas, en otros casos no conecta, se demora mucho tiempo, al final no hace nada.

desde el cliente conecto con:

```
ssh -N -X -R 22221:localhost:22 user@host
```

En el server ejecuto:

```
ssh -l user -p 22221 localhost
```

Y en el log del server he notado lo siguiente:

```
Jan  2 04:57:03 host sshd[29763]: Received disconnect from 192.24.25.12: 11: disconnected by user
Jan  2 04:58:03 host sshd[29771]: Accepted publickey for user from 192.24.25.12 port 56743 ssh2
Jan  2 04:58:04 host sshd[29773]: Received disconnect from 192.24.25.12: 11: disconnected by user
Jan  2 04:59:03 host sshd[29784]: Accepted publickey for user from 192.24.25.12 port 56743 ssh2
```

quizás alguien ya a pasado por esto o tiene alguien otra idea como realizar seguimiento.

Desde ya gracias por la posible respuestas.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Pequeña tontería pero, ¿Ya instalaste el servidor (no el cliente) ssh en tu cliente?

Es decir, en tu cliente ya corriste algo como.

```
$ sudo apt install openssh-server
$ sudo service ssh restart
```

Me pasa el mismo problema que a tí cuando no lo tengo instalado y también cuando, a pesar de instalarlo, aún no esta corriendo. Una vez puesto en marcha, el servidor ssh, no tengo problemas con ejecutar.

```
$ ssh -NX -f -R puerto:127.0.0.1:22 usuario@remote_host  # En el cliente
$ ssh -l mi_usuario 127.0.0.1 -p puerto  # En el servidor
```